# Is the High Availability of a system same as Availability in CAP Theorem?

Tags: database, cluster-computing, distributed, high-availability

I'm confused with the definition of things.

In my view **High Availability** is the property of a system that aims to ensure an *agreed* level of operational *performance* and usually is expressed as a percentage of uptime in a given year.

On another side **Availability** in CAP theorem state that in a distributed system, reads and writes would always succeed even when network connectivity is unavailable between nodes.

Therefore I assumed that these two things are absolutely different.

If this true, could we say that the distributed system may be **High Available** and don't have a property of **Availability** simultaneously in terms of CAP and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very much correct in your understanding that the terms ***High Availability*** *(which is used in the context of Cluster Solutions)* and ***Availability*** *(which is used in the context of CAP theorem to describe ***Accessibility*** of the data stored in the distributed system)* are completely different.

In the CAP theorem, the term ***Partitioning*** *(P of CAP)* refers to ***High Availability***.

Yes, a distributed system can possess ***High Availability*** (i.e. **Partitioning**) and not have ***Availability*** (*i.e. **Accessibility***) or vice versa. In this scenario the system can achieve ***Consistency*** *(C of CAP)* in both the cases.